# Prevent deleting folders in outlook 2007/2010 vba

Tags: vba, email, outlook, directory

I have some colleagues that delete some folders from a shared inbox and is driving me crazy.

I asked them to be more careful but they just don't give a ^%&* .  So I got an vba to put on all the users to prevent them deleting anything from that shared mailbox, but the code doesn't work.

Any help is welcomed.

```
 Public WithEvents objCritFolder_EIE_E3Imp As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Public WithEvents objCritFolder_EIE_E3Man As Outlook.MAPIFolder

 Private Sub application_Startup()
 Dim ns As Namespace
 Dim objRootFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

 Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

 Set objRootFolder = ns.Folders("MailBox - FOR ALL").Folders("Teams")
 Set objCritFolder_EIE_E3Imp = objRootFolder.Folders("TODAY")
 Set objCritFolder_EIE_E3Man = objRootFolder.Folders("TODAY + 1")
 Set objRootFolder = Nothing
 End Sub

 Private Sub objCritFolder_EIE_E3Imp_BeforeFolderMove(ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, cancel As Boolean)
 Dim strMsg As String
 cancel = True
 strMsg = "You can't move the TODAY folder."
 MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical, "Folder Move Not Allowed"
 End Sub
 Private Sub objCritFolder_EIE_E3Man_BeforeFolderMove(ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, cancel As Boolean)
 Dim strMsg As String
 cancel = True
 strMsg = "You can't move the TODAY + 1 folder."
 MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical, "Folder Move Not Allowed"
 End Sub
```

The problem is at :

```
 Public WithEvents objCritFolder_EIE_E3Imp As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Public WithEvents objCritFolder_EIE_E3Man As Outlook.MAPIFolder
```

It gives me: " object does not source automation events "

Comment: "does not source" - you can't do this - the object you're trying to add automation events to doesn't support automation events.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to recreate the error. Fixed it by removing MAPI from MAPIFolder.

```
Public WithEvents objCritFolder_EIE_E3Imp As Outlook.Folder
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that it kind of works. The problem is that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work. i made a sub init() to declare all the folders and put call init in the application_Startup but it doesn't take it. i have to manually run the init sub to work.